# Adobe Illustrator cursor is a pencil beside a circle with line through, how to remove that?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Due to this sign on the screen, many drawing tools are not performing their functions. Even after restarting Illustrator this sign doesn't disappear.
What should I do to get rid of this sign?

[image]

Comment: You're using Adobe Illustrator but you're unable to make a screenshot?

Comment: @ThomasWeller most operating systems don't include the cursor in a screenshot, and this icon is part of the cursor

Answer (score 9):

The little "Don't" symbol (circle with a line through it) means you **can't** perform whatever it is you are trying to perform.

In the case of drawing tools such as the Pencil tool, it means you can't draw where you are trying to draw. Most likely because the active Layer in the Layer Panel is *locked or hidden*

Answer (score 7):

It most likely means that your layer that you're working in is locked.

Either unlock the layer (or even specific object) or make a new one to work on.